# How to select all but the 3 last columns of a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to select all but the 3 last columns of my dataframe.

I tried :

```
df.loc[:,-3]
```

But it does not work

Edit : title

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Select everything **EXCEPT the last 3 columns**, do this using `iloc`:

```
In [1639]: df
Out[1639]: 
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  3  2  2  2
1  2  4  1  1  1

In [1640]: df.iloc[:,:-3]
Out[1640]: 
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
```

Answer (score 9):

Use this `df.columns` being sliced, and putted into a `df[...]` bracket:

```
print(df[df.columns[:-3]])
```